# How to keep if condition to check the browser is IE in extjs?

Tags: extjs

I have a requirement to check if application is opened using IE then my code should execute or else no..here is sample code..

```
                           xtype: 'panel',

                                header: true,
                                if(browser == ie){
                                height: 160,
                                  }
                                height: 150
                                width: 355,
                                layoutConfig: {
                                    align: 'center',
                                    padding: 10
                                },
```

Thanks,

Rajasekhar

Answer (score 2):

Use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
header: true,
height: ( Ext.isIE ? 160 : 150),
width: 355,
```

UPDATE
replaced `(browser == ie)` with `Ext.isIE`.

UPDATE2
Another alternative to using ternary operator is using [immediate function](http://javascriptmountain.com/2011/06/functions/immediate-functions-in-javascript-the-basics/):

```js
header: true,
height: (function() {
  if (Ext.isIE)
    return 160;
  //else if (Ext.isChrome)
  //  return something else;
  else
    return 150;
}),
width: 355,
```

One more alternative is to define variable containing the needed height before setting up the panel's config:

```js
// this is done before setting up config, but in the same scope
var neededHeight = 150;
if (Ext.isIE)
  neededHeight = 160;

// setting up config
  // ...
  height: neededHeight,
  // ...
```

Comment: @pllee, I think the idea was to show how ternary operator can help in this situation. Besides, the code will work if `ie` and `browser` variables are defined in the same scope.

Comment: @pllee, you are right. However, as Bobik said the idea was to show how ternary operator can help in this situation. Updated my answer though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Ext.isIE property to determine if the browser is IE or not.

```
height: Ext.isIE ? 160 : 150
```